# Keeping specific columns in read_excel

Tags: r, col

I am importing an excel file into R. I only want to keep columns A and C not B (columns are A,B,C in order), but the following code keeps column B too. How can I get rid of column B without subseting in another line of code?

```
df <- read_excel("df.xlsm", "futsales", range = cell_cols(c("A","C")), na = " ")
```

Comment: Why not read all data, and then select columns of interest, i.e. `library(tidyverse); read_excel("df.xlsm", "futsales", na = " ") %>% select(c("A", "C"))`?

Answer (score 8):

By going through the documentation for `read_excel` function, you have to give a range like,

```
df <- read_excel("df.xlsm", "futsales", range = cell_cols("A:C"), na = " ")
```

Comment: Still this one keeps column B, too. I want to only have columns A and C.

Comment: I don't think you can do that using read_excel function. Try other libraries maybe

Comment: You can use the col_types argument and enter "skip" for the columns you don't want. Something like col_types = c("text", "skip", "text")

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't specify multiple ranges in the range parameter of `read_excel`. However, you can use the map function from `purrr` to apply `read_excel` to a vector of ranges. In your use case, `map_dfc` will bind the column A and C selections back together into a single output dataset.

```
library(readxl)
library(purrr)

path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
ranges <- list("A", "C")
ranges %>% 
  purrr::map_dfc(
    ~ read_excel(
      path, 
      range = cell_cols(.))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this to successfully read in 5 columns of an Excel file with 27 columns, so here is how you can do it for a file with name you have stored in `x` and retrieving only first and third columns, assuming that column A is text and column C is numeric:

```
library(tibble)
library(readxl)
df.temp <- as.tibble(read_excel(x,
              col_names=TRUE,                             
              col_types=c("text","skip","numeric")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option of what @MauritsEvers said would be:

```
df <- read_excel("df.xlsm", "futsales")[,c(1,3)]
```

You are making a matrix with all the data, and at the same time, making `df` with all the rows (that's why the `[,`), and only the first ("A") and third ("C") columns (that's why the `,c(1,3)]`)